# Avoid Infinite recursion with Swift Operator Definitions?

Tags: recursion, swift, operator-overloading, infinite-loop

I'm following along with a Tic Tac Toe swift tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkYpoRj-7hA.

I've been making changes to the code as I progress such as creating structs and enums to better structure the entities in the code. I wanted to create an equality operator for two optional Structs called "Player." This operator would return false if either argument was nil or if their "kind" fields weren't equal (kinds are an enum). Here is the code I wrote to do this:

```
1.  @infix func == ( left: Player?, right: Player? ) -> Bool
2.  {
3.     var isEqual = false
4.
5.     if( left? == nil || right? == nil )
6.     {
7.         isEqual = false
8.     }
9.
10.    if( left!.kind == right!.kind )
11.    {
12.         isEqual = true
13.    }
14.
15.    return isEqual
16. }
```

The problem is that I believe it's being called recursively on itself when I check for nil (line 5). It crashes at runtime with the call stack listing this function over and over.

Questions: Is my hypothesis that this is triggering infinite recursion correct? If so is this a bug in Swift or is this how it ought to work? Is there a way to check for equality with nil without the function calling itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use switch

```
switch left {
    case .None: return false
    default: break
}
```

Also, your implementation <del>return false</del> crash if <del>both</del> `left` or `right` are `nil`

Fixed version

```
@infix func == ( left: Player?, right: Player? ) -> Bool
{
    var leftIsNil = false

    switch left {
        case .None: leftIsNil = true
        default: break
    }

    var rightIsNil = false

    switch right {
        case .None: rightIsNil = true
        default: break
    }

    if leftIsNil || rightIsNil {
        return leftIsNil == rightIsNil // return true if both nil
    } 

    return left!.kind == right!.kind // return true if both same kind
}
```

if `Kind?` is equatable

```
@infix func == ( left: Player?, right: Player? ) -> Bool
{
    return left?.kind == right?.kind
}
```

Comment: I was intending to return false if both arguments were nil. Seems like a bad idea now that I think about it. I'll push the nil checking into the code that uses this. Thanks for your help. Would you consider this a bug? It seems like it should be possible to define an operator and use that operator in the definition without recursively calling itself right?

Comment: I won't call it a bug. Because sometimes we do want recursively call. e.g. Compare a tree, we want recursively call `==` on left child and right child unless it is leaf node.

Answer (score 1):

@Gouldsc I had a similar problem with checking for nil in another piece of code, @BryanChen definitely has the right idea in declaring the `nils` as booleans and then putting through an `if` statement.

I am working off of Skip's tutorial as well as I was wondering if you had any issue with the AI Turn when testing the app on a device? Or had any insight as to other ways to write the AI Turn part of the app?

Comment: I've noticed at least one logical error in his AI code. I'm working on refactoring it (trying to use different features in Swift) to learn the language better. I'll post a link here if I ever manage to finish it.

Comment: @Gouldsc Alright, good idea. If you end up posting the refactored version, I would greatly appreciate if you would tag me in the post.